# Bamboo integration for HockeyApp and Android

Tags: android, continuous-integration, bamboo, hockeyapp

We are using HockeyApp for our Android application.

We want to automate all the deployment process. We started using Bamboo to build our .apk file and final step would be to distribute it to Hockey.

After a lot of browsing on the internet, I couldn't found any plugin available to do that. The only thing I found out available was: IOS, Cocoa and Xcode Support for Bamboo plugin - but this is for IOS only.

If there is no other plugin for Bamboo to use maybe someone knows a way that we can automate the process to distribute the .apk to Hockey? (e.g. write a script or something that HockeyApp supports).

Thank you,

Luisa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some tinkering I found a method that works for me. I added an additional Script to the Build Job and used the following in the script body (be sure to use the apk filename in your config):

```
curl \
  -F "status=2" \
  -F "notify=1" \
  -F "notes=Some new features and fixed bugs." \
  -F "notes_type=0" \
  -F "ipa=@app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk" \
  -H "X-HockeyAppToken: AppTokenHere" \
  https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/upload
```